# Do Wookiees emit a characteristic / unpleasant odor?

Tags: star-wars, aliens

Do we have canon commentary or events which demonstrate whether Wookiees emit a characteristic odor?   Do they smell like wet dog when wet?

Comment: I want to say that in the game *Knights of the Old Republic* the character Mission Vao makes an offhand comment on the smell of Zaalbar at some point. But it has been a long time since I've played and aren't sure if, when, or what was actually said.

Comment: odor is a canon part of the SW universe: "I don't care what you smell, get in there you hairy oaf", "what a wonderful smell you've discovered". Lasat odor was referenced a few times in Rebels. it isn't unreasonable to ask if there has been a reference to Chewie having an odor @Edlothiad. I have edited the question / title to be more direct and obvious that there is a canon answer (yes, no, don't know) - but it isn't opinion based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Solo junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story:_Junior_Novel) Han notes that Chewie has an unpleasant odour. This is likely down to the fact that his fur is wet but also the fact that he may not have been able to sufficiently cleanse himself from a *single* shower after having been in a pen for weeks/months.

> He turned and looked at the Wookiee directly in front of him, **whose
>   wet fur didn’t smell much better than it had before the shower.** “We
>   couldn’t have done this, maybe, one at a time?”

He certainly smells bad when wet, but Wookiees are renowned for their general cleanliness

> He dragged a fingertip through a puddle of purple goop and inhaled the scent. The last time he would smell this extinct flower, and he would forever associate it with **the scent of wet Wookiee**. He began to tally the bill he planned on handing Beckett at the end of this whole thing, the one that marked down everything he and his crew ate, drank, or smudged with even a tiny mark on his beloved Falcon.
>   
> ...
>   He sighed and removed his cape. He couldn’t fly knowing his bath looked like this. **“People say Wookiees are clean,”** he muttered, rolling up his sleeves. “Now we know how they get that way.” He leaned over the shower drain. Might as well start with all the hair.

That being said, Han does note that he's "smelly" in The [Force Awakens novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novelization)). One assumes that he kinda smells like a living room carpet. Not bad from any sort of distance but *noticeably unpleasant when you're close-up*.

> “Get up! Chewie, get up!” Striving to divide his attention between the
>   wounded Wookiee and the gang members who were trying to break out of
>   the far corridor, Han got one arm underneath Chewbacca and strained
>   with all his might. It was like trying to lift a mountain. **A big,
>   heavy, hairy, smelly, and badly bleeding mountain**. One that he would
>   no more leave behind than he would his ship or himself.

Answer (score 1):

According to old Lucasfilm Star Wars: Databank about Wookiees (11-11-2007), Wookiees have a keen sense of smell. Such reference actually doesn’t exist in the cited databank but it can be found in other sources like Wikipedia ([Wikipedia-Wookiee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wookiee) ). The aforementioned faculty of perceiving smells implies that they can use their olfactory sense to detect closeness of other Wookiees or humans (like when Chewbacca smells Han Solo before he (Solo) enters the large cell where Chewy was confined in the Cloud city in Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back).

I think, in the Star Wars universe, Wookiees smell like Wookiees. It is a combination of several of their specific smell causers: secreted saliva, sweat, and other body fluids.

Out of the universe, during a Twitter question and answer session about Chewbacca, Donald Glover said about Chewbacca: "He smells so good because there's conditioner on him, it smells really good." ['Solo: A Star Wars Story' Cast Reveals How Many Times They Hugged Chewbacca](https://comicbook.com/starwars/2018/05/13/solo-a-star-wars-story-reveals-chewbacca-hugs/)

Comment: That's because he just doused himself in Lando's conditioners, not what he smells like normally.